# Trouble with showing a factored expression

Tags: sequences-and-series

I had a go at expanding and simplifying to prove the first part of this, but couldn't get anywhere, any ideas ? 
Thanks.

Show that for every integer n≥0,
$$u^n-v^n=(u-v)(u^{n-1}+u^{n-2}v+...+uv^{n-2}+v^{n-1})=(u-v) \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}u^{n-1-k}v^k$$

Comment: You want to remove the last "$=$" sign

Comment: You are unable to prove the above equality, is that right?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: @caleb   Do you know the equtation $x^n -1 = (x-1) (x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} + \cdots + x + 1) $?

Comment: No I haven't seen that equation before

Comment: Thank you @bing, the next part is to differentiate $f(x)=x^{3/7}$ for all x≠0 using this formula, and the definition of a derivative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's straight-forward if you expand the right hand side, you'll get:
$$(u-v)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}u^{n-1-k}v^k=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}u^{n-k}v^k-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}u^{n-k-1}v^{k+1}$$
$$=u^n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}n^{n-k}v^k - \sum_{k=0}^{n-2}u^{n-k-1}v^{k+1} - v^n$$
$$=u^n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}n^{n-k}v^k - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}n^{n-k}v^k - v^n=u^n - v^n$$